# Cannot Run My Hybrid Application Project on CordovaSim

Tags: android, cordova, jboss, eclipse-plugin, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm Using Eclipse Luna and Java 7 and JBoss Developer Studio 8.1.0 GA to create a Hybrid Mobile Application that will communicate with another JEE project using REST Webservices .

I've Followed the steps of installation and configuration for Eclipse **THym**
and When I reach the step of selecting an android engine for my hybrid App I get this Warning from Eclipse

[image]

and When I ignore it and try to launch my App on Cordova Simulator (CordovaSim) I get an internal Error.

[image]

Is there any suggested solutions ? I've updated everything but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Well there seems to be a problem with Eclipse **THym** and JBoss Developer Studio 8.0 , So the solution for me was to install Java 8 and JBoss Developer Studio 9 and I changed Also my Eclipse to 4.5 and Everything works fine .